# Exponentiation in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I feel like this is a fairly straightforward question, but I've been having a great deal of difficult computing one modular arithmetic expression. It's this:

$9 ≡ 3^a \pmod{17}$

How does one go about approaching a problem like this? I'll feel like the solution is much simpler than I'm making it.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share your own thoughts and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please note that if you're asked to *solve* the congruence, you should be finding all $a$’s that make the congruence true, not just the obvious one. And you do understand, don't you, that the $a$ in question is an ordinary integer, not something to be read modulo 17?

Answer (score 1):

Keep multiplying 3 by itself and then dividing by 17 and taking the remainder until you get to 9!

Comment: ..until you get to factorial $9$?

Comment: You can stop whenever you like Ahmed ;-)

Comment: I ended up just making a python script to do this. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some tool like Fermat little theorem: $3^{16} = 1\pmod {17} \to a = 2, 18, 34, \cdots, 2+16k$,..